# CsvProvider skips first row with data

Tags: f#, f#-data

There is a CSV file without headers. Only the rows with data. In order to set the headers I use sample.

```fs
type DisaggreggatedFinancialData = CsvProvider<"Schema.csv", HasHeaders=true, AssumeMissingValues=true, MissingValues=".">
```

When loading a file CsvProvider is not reads the first row of data. Data is only available from the second row. When specify the parameter HasHeaders = false, then the sample headers are not available. How to set headers and read data from the first row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave HasHeaders=false and use the Schema parameter to specify the names of the columns:

```
let csv = CsvProvider<"1,2,3", HasHeaders = false, Schema = "Duration (float<second>),foo,float option">.GetSample()
```

From the [CsvProvider Help](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/CsvProvider.html):

> If the first row of the file is not a header row, you can specify the HasHeaders static parameter to false in order to consider that row as a data row. In that case, the columns will be named Column1, Column2, etc..., unless the names are overridden using the Schema parameter. Note that you can override only the name in the Schema parameter and still have the provider infer the type for you.

Comment: Thank you! It works. But only when I explicitly use strings for sampling and schema. When I used the files - it didn't work.